# File name case change throws Os.error[errorno 2] python on CentOs 7

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, centos7

```
import os
path="/home/jayabalan/Desktop/testdocker"
for i in os.listdir(path):
        os.rename(i,i.upper())
```

Running the above code on CentOS 7 throws an error as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "casechange.py", line 4, in <module>
    os.rename(i,i.upper())
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But when I tried printing the files by adding "print (i)" lists the file correctly inside the folder "testdocker"

The same problem happens while running this casechange program in windows.

```
"C:\Program Files\Python\python.exe" "G:/pycharm projects/jaitestpractice/practicefile.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/pycharm projects/jaitestpractice/practicefile.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.rename(i, i.replace(" ", "_").upper())
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'jfas.txt' -> 'JFAS.TXT'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to prepend the path to the file.

```
os.path.join(path, i)
```

The problem is `listdir` only returns file names and will look in the current directory for the file.

So:

```
import os
path="/home/jayabalan/Desktop/testdocker"
for i in os.listdir(path):
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, i), i.upper())
```

Comment: But how listdir prints the files correctly in the said directory when I give print(i) statement below the for loop?

Comment: It prints the filename, but not the file name with the path. `os.rename` doesn't know where the file is, it just has a string.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks a lot!!